# nuxt 3 and useState - state update not reflecting globablly

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

In my app.vue I am doing something similar to this,

```
<template>
   <Transition>
       <div class="overlay__mask" v-if="overlayVisble"></div>
  </Transition>
</template>
<script setup>
    const overlayVisible = useState('overlayVisible', () => { return false });
</script>
```

In another component I am doing this following,

```
<template>
    button @click="overlayVisible = !overlayVisible">Toggle Overlay</button>
</template>

<script setup>
    const overlayVisible = useState('overlayVisible');
</script>
```

What I would expect to happen that when the button is clicked in my component it updates the value of overlayVisible and anything that is using that state reflects the change, however my `overlay_mask` in app.vue never renders so I assume it thinks overlayVisible is always false?

Comment: `<button...` ? I'm guessing.

Comment: You should using composable to create global state.  Check sample on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tender-kirch-k7gm2h